# Error in console: uncaught error history.js adapter has already been loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, activecollab

I'm creating an small module for activeCollab composed by some webpages. I'm using PHP and Javascript/jQuery/AJAX. When I enter into the main page of the module I'm creating everything is working fine, but if later I try to go to other modules my web application is crashing. Is not showing any information. The only way for reviving it is refreshing the navigator.

If I check the error console of my navigator, I see that when I'm exiting from my custom webpage it says

```
`Uncaught Error: History.js Adapter has already been loaded...`
```

The header of my HTML file has this information:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And this code is making my Javascript functions work properly.

What can be happening? I googled and I didn't found much information about this issue. Every help would be appreciated.

Comment: load jquery before ui.js

Comment: I followed this advise but it didn't work. I found a solution by my own, thanks @Nisam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved it, the problem was that my application is loading by default its own jQuery file and there was a conflict between this one and the ones I was trying to import. The solution was easy: I only had to delete the lines I wrote inside the "head" tag.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does that mean your "application is loading by default its own jQuery file". Where was it loading its own jquery file, if not in the <head> where you showed what scripts you were loading. As far as I can tell you were only loading one jQuery file.